# xcopy and invalid drive specification

Tags: windows-xp, xcopy

I am trying to use xcopy and it always returns with invalid drive specification

xcopy "C:\socp.tar"  "\\FMDX1024\C\socp.tar"

FMDX1024 is a machine on the network.

any clue?

Comment: Are you missing a colon off that second "C"

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the hidden admin share which is C$, unless you actually have shared a drive with the share name C.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe:

```
xcopy "C:\socp.tar" "\\FMDX1024\C$\socp.tar"
```

C$ is an [Administrative share](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share), which must be enabled by undoing Simple File Sharing.

See :
[How to enable in Windows XP SP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share#How_to_enable_in_Windows_XP_SP3)
[How to enable hidden administrative shares on XP Home edition](http://www.oakdome.com/lab/?page_id=141)

Answer (score 0):

If I put in a valid path, XCOPY completes successfully for me.

If I purposely put in an invalid path, XCOPY returns, "Invalid drive specification".

So guessing what you think you have, you do not.
Either the \\FMDX1024\ or C\ is incorrect (& it need not be "C\", it could be called anything).

C:\TMP>xcopy xxx.txt \\therube\c_drive\tmp\xxx.txt

C:xxx.txt

1 File(s) copied

C:\TMP>xcopy xxx.txt \\therube\c\tmp\xxx.txt

Invalid drive specification

0 File(s) copied